# Uso del verbo "inoltrare" nell'ambito dell'informatica

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Su [questo video](https://youtu.be/xY638IwzKBY) si può ascoltare questa frase:

> Verificate le fonti e i mittenti di messaggi, link e video per evitare di **inoltrare** trojan, virus e altre contenuti dannosi.

Il significato di "inoltrare" si può più o meno capire dal contesto. Una ricerca su Google mi ha fatto vedere che si tratta di un verbo molto usato nel settore dell'informatica. Potreste farmi alcuni altri esempi di uso di tale verbo in quest'ambito?

Comment: Inoltrare può anche significare "procedere", o andare avanti in generale. Ad esempio, è perfettamente corretta una frase come: *da giovane si inoltrò nella jungla*. Si potrebbe anche usare in frasi come *inoltriamoci in quel negozio*, ma, all'orecchio moderno quantomeno, suona strano ed antiquato.

Comment: Puoi usare anche il suo sinonimo [*forwardare*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/forwardare/), se vuoi *trollare* un po' i puristi dell'italiano utenti di questo sito.  :)

Comment: Si usa anche in ambito burocratico, contabile e simili.. ad esempio "L'avvocato inoltró la pratica all"ufficio competente", non significa per forza la inoltró per mail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Inoltrare* in questo contesto ha lo stesso significato dell'inglese *to forward*. È utilizzato per descrivere l'atto di mandare ad un destinatario una copia di un'email che si ha ricevuto. Per esempio

> Ho comprato il biglietto d'aereo e ti ho inoltrato l'email di conferma.
>
> Quest'email che mi ha mandato mia sorella è troppo divertente, te la inoltro subito.
>
> Purtroppo questo problema va al di là delle mie competenze, ma ho inoltrato la sua richiesta ad un collega che si occupa di queste situazioni.

Answer (score 2):

In informatica il verbo inoltrare si può intendere ad esempio come ***inoltrare la posta elettronica*** (in inglese forward), funzione che consente di trasmettere automaticamente i messaggi in arrivo su una casella verso un altro indirizzo.

Nell'ambito delle reti esiste il [bridge](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(informatica)) (ponte) che ha funzioni di inoltrare pacchetti o frame:

> Quando riceve un frame su una porta, cerca di capire dall'indirizzo
>   del destinatario se questi si trova nello stesso segmento del mittente
>   oppure no. Nel primo caso evita di ***inoltrare*** il frame, in quanto
>   presumibilmente il destinatario l'ha già ricevuto per condivisione del
>   bus di comunicazione. Nel secondo caso, invece, il bridge ***inoltra*** la
>   trama verso il segmento in cui si trova effettivamente il
>   destinatario.

Nell'esempio che tu citi il verbo inoltrare ha come significato trasmettere, diffondere possibili veicoli di infezione da virus informatico

Comment: L'inoltro delle email non è per forza una cosa automatica. Di solito si fa manualmente, scegliendo l'apposita opzione, per inviare una copia dell'email ad un altro destinatario.